# Using custom css - hide minicart

Tags: magento2, css

I created a local.css file that works well with this content:

```
.action.primary.tocart {
    display: none;
}
```

However, I want to use it to hide the minicart:

```
<a class="action showcart" href="site here" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'"><span class="text">My Cart</span>
```

This is not working:

```
.action.showcart {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    height: 1px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the minicart by the following rule:

```
.minicart-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` is to prevent content from overflowing outside a container.

you need to use `display: none;`

But remember the minicart will still be contained within the flow of the HTML, so needlessly adding to the payload.

My theme framework (JetTheme) allows me to turn off the Minicart completely, maybe yours does too.

If not, you could probably remove it in your layout XML.